# How to get int from a line of a text and add them together in c++?

Tags: c++

Hi I have got an text file and inside writing:

```
15 7 152 3078 
178 352 1 57
```

What I want to do is get the int's from first line, sum up the numbers and make it an integer. And than do it for the second line with another int. How can I do that with c++? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringstream` to convert a string into integer. And to sum a vector of integer, use `accumulate` algorithm. You can pass a filename as first argument to the program, by default the program assume the filename as `input.txt`.

Here is a complete program to demonstrate this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>  // for accumulate
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::string filename{"input.txt"};
    if(argc > 1) {
        filename = argv[1];
    }

    // open the input file
    std::ifstream inputFile(filename);
    if(!inputFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open " << filename << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::string line;
    // read the file line by line
    while(getline(inputFile, line)) {
        if(line.empty()) continue;

        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::vector<int> v;
        int x;
        // extract the content as integer from line
        while(ss >> x) {
            v.push_back(x);
        }
        // add them all
        auto total = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
        std::cout << total << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have been a really big help to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As in Aamir's answer, but with separate listing of sums and numbers per line. Maybe that helps too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::string filename{"input.txt"};
    if(argc > 1) {
        filename = argv[1];
    }

    // open the input file
    std::ifstream inputFile(filename);

    if(!inputFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open " << filename << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<int> v_numberSum;
    std::vector<int> v_numbersPerLine;

    std::string line;

    // read the file line by line

    int i = 0;

    while(getline(inputFile, line)) {
        if(line.empty()) continue;

        v_numberSum.push_back(0);
        v_numbersPerLine.push_back(0);

        std::stringstream f(line);
        std::string s;

        int cnt = 0;

        while (getline(f, s, ' ')) {
            v_numberSum[i] += std::stoi(s);
            cnt++;
        }

        v_numbersPerLine[i] = cnt;
        i++;
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (auto intItem: v_numberSum){
        std::cout << "sum"<<j<<": " << intItem << " numbers per line: " << v_numbersPerLine[j] << std::endl;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code helped too.

Comment: Btw is there a way to know how many numbers is there on a line? I got the numbers to a pointer but I don't know how to count them so I can make pointer with same length as count of numbers.

Comment: @Kardok_Delikaya also numbers per line